Outdated XML processor is present on the classpath
Getting below error:

Enabling XXE protection failed. The attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD is not supported by the TransformerFactory. This usually mean an outdated XML processor is present on the classpath (e.g. Xerces, Xalan). If you are not able to resolve the issue by fixing the classpath, the hazelcast.ignoreXxeProtectionFailures system property can be used to disable XML External Entity protections. We don't recommend disabling the XXE as such the XML processor configuration is unsecure!: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD.

Tried disabling the hazelcast.ignoreXxeProtectionFailures

You are probably failing a schema check.  Try using a xml online checker to find errors : https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator

The error message itself suggests two solutions: changing the classpath to remove the outdated processor, and/or setting a property hazelcast.ignoreXxeProtectionFailures to disable the check.
You're asking us to suggest a different solution, but before we do that we need to understand why the two suggested solutions don't work for you.
